# How does google search get a precise location stronger than ip address

Tags: google-location-services

I am wondering how google search tracks the precise city location, as it seems stronger than simply locating an IP address. Basically, from the IP to location services I am using, I get an approximate location but in most cases it is not as exact as google's (city, zipCode, etc.). Google's location tracking on google.com is much stronger than any other IP to location services (from the internet). I am not signed in to a google account and I did not allow google to use the precise location. Is there any explanation as to why google.com is able to track so accurately. It seems that it may consider more than just client IP. I am using a computer (not a phone).

Comment: Tag wiki for [tag:google-location-services] says: "Your location could be determined using data from cellular, Wi-Fi or Global Positioning System (GPS) networks"

Answer (score 1):

> How does Google search get accurate location stronger than IP address?

you are right. Google is more than just a search engine when you use the IP address service, it will get the user's Latitude and Longitude from which you can know the location of the user from but it is not as accurate as Google search.

Google uses GPS service in the Android operating system to get accurate user location and store it in your Google account, then you can use it in many other services like Google Search, Google Maps, Google Play, Youtube and all Google services.

Google also gets your location from the Web Search Engine but it is not as accurate as GPS. Also if you use Google services; Time and time will store Google Loaction very accurate.

That's all I know about Google products. Maybe my information wasn't very accurate but I did my best.